# I applied for an extension of the Thailand 45 day visa, but I was only granted 75 days instead of the 90 days I requested

Tags: visas, thailand, israeli-citizens

I entered Thailand on February 11, 2022 and received a 45-day stamp on my passport (from November 11 to December 16).

Today, I went to the immigration office in Phuket to extend my visa and was only granted an extension until January 15. This is strange because it is only 75 days, when I should have been granted an extension until February 2. Wasn't the purpose of the new post-Covid-19 visa to be for **90** days?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Israeli.........

Comment: I'd imagine that 90 days is the *maximum* and that immigration officers are free to give you anything between "nope" and the maximum time.

Comment: @PeterM that's an answer, and basically a complete one

Comment: @mlc It's a generic, obvious, glib answer, but to me it falls short of an official answer because I know nothing about Thailand and its immigration policies.

Comment: Thailand immigration is a mystery.  You might have luck going back in pleading your case, especially if you have paid reservations that you can show past the date provided, though it's unlikely.  At this point, your best bet is likely to be a border run.  It can be a nice chance to enjoy Thailand's scenic train routes...  If you are planning to ask for another 45 day extension after a border run, be sure to state that clearly before the passport is stamped, preferably with paid reservations documented and in-hand.  That's no guarantee, though.

Answer (score 9):

Israel is one of the [64 Countries](https://image.mfa.go.th/mfa/0/mkKfL2iULZ/%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A8/Summary_of_countries_and_territories_entitled.pdf) allowed to enter Thailand under the *Tourist Visa Exemption Scheme*. This is a different from a *visa on arrival* or a *tourist visa*.

When you entered Thailand on Nov 2nd, you did **not** get a visa, you got a "visa exemption" and a permit to stay for 45 days.

While in Thailand under this status, you are allowed to ask for an extension of your stay (as always, at the discretion of the immigration officer), which is going to be for an extra 30 days. This is what you got and it is the maximum extension for this type of entry.

---

The "90 days Covid tourist visa" you are referring to is a type of visa you have to get at an embassy before your trip. It is an extension of the old 60 days tourist visa. It was extended from 60 to 90 days to accomodate the mandatory quarantine during Covid. The quarantine is not necessary anymore and this visa is still available for now but is supposed to be reverted to the classic 60 days visa at the end of March 2023.